# Nullable int check in Expression Tree .Net

Tags: .net, linq, expression-trees

I want to filter on a nullable property using Expression Tree.

Eg.

```
Items.Where(item => item.myNullableIntProperty == null)
```

Using `Expression.Equal(property, value)` results in no data being returned. Is there another way to check this?

```
var value = Expression.Constant(null);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "MyNullableIntPropertyName");
var expression = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(value));

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(expression , parameter);
lambda.Compile();
query.Where(lambda);
```

Edit:
This code works for all other values except null

Comment: Are you generating expression tree for ORM? What is `value`?

Comment: updated the question with more info

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FZEWwC). Please add minimal reproducable example.

Comment: The Expression works for you with a null value?

Comment: Please see the linked repro in my previous comment.

Comment: Turns out it was a different problem with my query where I was adding pagination to the query before trying to filter. Thanks :)

Comment: Was glad to help!